# Different structure names but same structure variables - How to make each structure variable unique?

Tags: c++, structure

I have 4 files. 3 of them are headers and one of it is something you would call a main handler. These are the content of the file that are causing the problem.

main.cpp

```
#include "NPSJF.cpp"
#include "PSJF.cpp"
#include "RR.cpp"


int main(){
NPSJFmain();
PSJFmain();
RRmain();

return 0;
}
```

NPSJF.cpp

```
//Created struct to store the values
struct process{
    char pid[50];                                                                                       //declare variables 
    int arrival_time;
    int burst_time;
}a[50]
```

PSJF.cpp

```
struct node {
    char pname;
    int btime;
    int atime;
    int ctime=0;
    int wtime;
}a[1000],b[1000],c[1000]
```

RR.cpp

```
struct pro{
    char process;
    int burst;
    int arrival;
    int ctime=0;
    int wait=-1;
}a[100],b[100],c[100];
```

All of them has the same structure variable, but they have different structure names. Compiling and running the main.cpp would show the error :

> PSJF.cpp   [Error] conflicting declaration 'node a [1000]'

> NPSJF.cpp  [Note] previous declaration as 'process a [50]'

I've tried putting typedef infront of each structure like so.

NPSJF.cpp

```
//Created struct to store the values
typedef struct process{
    char pid[50];                                                                                       //declare variables 
    int arrival_time;
    int burst_time;
}a[50];
```

and for the other files but it didn't work.

Comment: “.cpp” indicates C++ source files. Why have you tagged this C?

Comment: Your post does not contain any description of a problem, other than “it didn’t work.” You do not tell us what compiler error message you got or how the program misbehaved. When asking about something not working, you need to describe the problem in detail, including the messages or output that indicates the problem.

Comment: you have 3 global variables all called 'a'

Comment: Is the problem that the linker complained about multiple definitions of names? You could fix that by adding `static` to the beginnings of those declarations, which makes the name internal to each translation unit (static linkage). But that also requires that you compile them separately, and, when you describe them as headers but name them as “.cpp”, that suggests you might be compiling them all together in one translation unit.

Comment: you also claim to have 3 .cpp files, but then include .h files

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yea I forgot to add the error message. Sorry.

Comment: @pm100 initially was .h but i changed to .cpp after reading something about being able to declare same structure variable in different .cpp files , not .h . Was trying things while creating the question, my bad.

Comment: You are doing the equivalent of saying `int a; char a; float a;` inside a function.  In your code `a` is a variable name not a type or struct name.  A simple fix would be to use `node_a`,  `process_a`, etc.

Comment: Note that `#include <xyz.cpp>` is wrong anyway – you do not include source files, only header files (usually `.h` or `.hpp`) and at best files containing inline code (often `.i` or `.inl`). Either you are violating file naming conventions (using .cpp for some headers) or you have a fundamental design problem...

Comment: The thing about `#include`: Then the preprocessor (typically part of the compiler) spots a `#include` directive it replaces the directive with a copy of the named file. It doesn't matter what the included file is, as soon as you include it, it becomes part of the file you're compiling. If you include a jpg file, that probably won't compile, but in the past I have set up an array definition and popped something like `#include "data.csv"` inside the braces and used Excel to crap out the array data.

Comment: If you include a cpp file, it's going to follow all the same rules as any other included file. If you do things in the cpp file that should only be done in a compiled source file, you're going to feel the pain when the linker finds it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the “something” you read says you can declare different objects with the same name in different “.cpp” files but not “.h” files is that we use different “.cpp” files in separate compilations. Files named “.cpp” are used as primary source code files, whereas files named “.h” are used as header files. Source code files are used to separate source code, whereas header files are used to publish common things, thus connecting source code.

To do this correctly, you need to compile each source code file separately, making an object file. Then you link the object files together to make an executable file. If you have not done this before, you may need to learn new commands for compiling and linking, or you may need to learn new arrangements in your IDE (Integrated Development Environment) software.

In each source code file, you will need to put one group of functions and data that work together. Separate groups will go into each source code file. The header file associated with each source code file will declare only the things that are defined inside the source code file but intended to be used from outside of it, in other source code files. Each source code file will include the header files that provides the declarations it needs.

Further, when you define objects outside of any function that are not intended to be used from other source files, you can declare them `static` to prevent the linker from attempting to link them with other objects of the same name in other files. There are other C++ features for this, too, and you also should avoid declaring objects outside of functions. There are other design patterns that are better for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have 3 things with the same name in scope at the same time (even if they are different types), you must give them different names , like this

```
struct pro{
    char process;
    int burst;
    int arrival;
    int ctime=0;
    int wait=-1;
}pro_a[100],pro_bb[100],pro_c[100];
```

BTW, file names make no difference (.h.cpp. foo. bar)